# jQuery Mobile Calculation display not appearing

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm fairly new to the jQuery Mobile. I'm trying to build a calculator. I have created the script and the form however the output displays only when i click the calculate button the second time . Can you please help suggest what should i change?

below is the jquery script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function compute() {
    var p = parseInt($('#people').val());
    var b = parseInt($('#bill').val());
    var t = parseInt($('#tip').val());
    var totalwithtip =  (b + b * t/100).toFixed(2);
    $('#totalwithtip').val(totalwithtip);
    var perpersonwithouttip = (b / p).toFixed(2);
    $('#perpersonwithouttip').val(perpersonwithouttip);
    var perpersonwithtip = (totalwithtip / p).toFixed(2);
    $('#perpersonwithtip').val(perpersonwithtip);
    }
    $('#calculate').click(function(){
    if ($('#people').val() !== ""){
    $('#calculate').on("click", compute);
    } 
    else {
        alert("Please enter the number of people");
    }
    if ($('#bill').val() !== ""){
    $('#calculate').on("click", compute);
    } else {
        alert("Please enter the bill amount");
    }

    });

    $(":reset").css("background-color", "red");
    $('#calculate').css({"background-color": "green", "color": "white"});
});
```

Below is HTML:

```
<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <form method="post" action="demoform.asp"
        <div class="ui-field-contain">
            <label for="people">Number of People:</label>
            <input type="number" name="people" id="people">
            <label for="bill">Bill Amount:</label>
            <input type="number" name="bill" id="bill">
            <label for="tip"> Tip %:</label>
            <input type="number" name="tip" id="tip">

            <label for="totalwithtip"><b>Total with Tip% : $</b></label>
            <input type="text" name="totalwithtip" id="totalwithtip">

            <label for="perpersonwithouttip"><b>Share per person without Tip: $</b></label>
            <input type="text" name="perpersonwithouttip" id="perpersonwithouttip">

            <label for="perpersonwithtip"><b>Share per person with Tip: $</b></label>
            <input type="text" name="perpersonwithtip" id="perpersonwithtip">
            <br />
            <button id="calculate" data-inline="true">Calculate</button>
            <input type="reset" data-inline="true" value="Reset"/>
        </div>

    </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQueryMobile You should use PageEvents like:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function() {

});
```

rather than document ready. Please consider also using event "tap" instead of "click"

like this:

```
 $(body).on("tap" ,"#calculate", compute);
```

Comment: Thanks for this Kamil. I will use these going forward.

Comment: However my problem is still there - it does not calculate and show the results when i click the first time.

Comment: During my experience with jQueyMobile, I found also sometimes it's better to use full selectors like: $("div#id") etc.

What I do for testing is: open Chrome console and just try to see if selector gives You any content, by entering it. Often it will give You [ ] which means selector was not found.

Answer (score 0):

Try restructuring your code so that on pagecreate (I gave your page div an id of page1), you setup the click handler for the calculate button. In the handler, call compute() directly instead of attaching to another click handler:

```
function compute() {
    var p = parseInt($('#people').val());
    var b = parseInt($('#bill').val());
    var t = parseInt($('#tip').val());
    var totalwithtip =  (b + b * t/100).toFixed(2);
    $('#totalwithtip').val(totalwithtip);
    var perpersonwithouttip = (b / p).toFixed(2);
    $('#perpersonwithouttip').val(perpersonwithouttip);
    var perpersonwithtip = (totalwithtip / p).toFixed(2);
    $('#perpersonwithtip').val(perpersonwithtip);
}
$(document).on("pagecreate","#page1", function(){ 

    $('#calculate').on("click", function(){
        if ($('#people').val() == ""){
            alert("Please enter the number of people");
        } else if ($('#bill').val() == ""){
            alert("Please enter the bill amount");
        } else if ($('#tip').val() == ""){
            alert("Please enter the tip amount");
        } else {
            compute();   
        }
    });

    $(":reset").css("background-color", "red");
    $('#calculate').css({"background-color": "green", "color": "white"});
});
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/9st8ytco/)**

Comment: Makes sense. Works much better than the earlier version. thanks for your help.